# AWS Lambda role doesn't update when policy is removed

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, amazon-iam

I created a function that writes to dynamo and is associated with a custom role.
When I remove the policy from the role that allows writes to my dynamo table and test the function again, the function is still able to write to the table.

Why does a change to the role not take effect in the lambda function? Is this a bug?

I found that if I modify the description of the function and save it, the function now cannot write to dynamo as originally expected.

Comment: IAM role permissions updates take effect almost immediately even if that role is associated with a running instance. How much delay are you noticing?

Comment: [*"It may take a few minutes"*](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_temp_control-access_disable-perms.html)

Comment: Thanks, will brush up on that doc. I know STS is used for roles, but I thought it would issue a new token to lambda immediately.

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that all IAM role and policy management happens in us-east-1, so if you are running in another region it can take a little while for the changes to be replicated to the region you are in.

This isn't an issue with the token refresh. While it's true that a token is not revoked when there is a change, the permissions are always evaluated at the time of the request, not at the time the token was created.